# .htacces redirect only if there is a subfolder

Tags: php, laravel, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

At first I will explain what I need: I have a wordpress site and want to install a laravel system. After a lot of research saw that it was impossible to try to configure htaccess so that the dos run in the same folder, so installed Laravel in a subdomain.

I don't have anything in wordpress that runs only with a subfolder
(eg: **[www.dominio.com/folder](http://www.dominio.com/folder)** or **[www.dominio.com/folder**/](http://www.dominio.com/folder**/))
just the root of the domain (index.php) and in the articles (**[www.domain.com/999/title-title](http://www.domain.com/999/title-title)**).

My intention is for **any url with a subfolder** to be redirected to a subdomain
ex.:
"www.domain.com/folder" **or** "www.domain.com/folder/"
**go to**
"sub.domain.com.br"

However, this folder after the domain can be anything (not specific, using regex).

My current htaccess:

```
   <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On 
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index.php$ - [L] 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(stories) [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
    RewriteRule . /index.php 
  </IfModule>
```

I can't define any condition that satisfies this, and reading other articles and docs the most logical thing I came up with was to add this (below), but it doesn't work. Surely the condition or perhaps previous conditions aren't generating an incorrect result... or it just doesn't work out the way I want.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}/(.*)$  [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule  ^(.*)$  https://sub.domain.com [L,R=301]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Let’s say you want to redirect `www.domain.com/folder` directory to `folder.domain.com` subdomain.

We can use the Apache rewrite rule to accomplish this.

```bash
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^/folder/(.*)$ http://sub.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

As you said you installed Laravel in a subdirectory you can try the option below which can be used to redirect `/folder` to `folder.domain.com`. This will work for both `www.domain.com` and `domain.com`

```bash
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?folder/(.*)$ http://folder.domain.com/$1 [R=301]
```

Comment: "folder" as an example. I want any URL, not specifically "Folder".

Comment: Okay, then replace the  `^/?folder/(.*)$` with `^(.*)$`. it will work. if my answer helps you kindly mark it useful.

Comment: This condition will redirect the entire site to the subdomain. I think you forgot that there are already other conditions in htacces. When there is only ONE (second, any name) folder in the url I want to redirect... when there is more than one or none do nothing.

Comment: I have no problem setting the new rule. I can't determine the right condition for it to consider only when there is one (and only one) folder after the domain.